# SharePoint Term Store - Mandatory level of choice?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, term-store

In a SharePoint list we have a managed metadata column based on term store values.

The term store is a hierarchy of 4 levels.

Is it possible to force all users to always select a value from minimum the third level?

[image: Metadata in SharePoint - 4 levels]

Best regards
Morten

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the managed metadata column, and change the Term Set Settings section, select third level term and save, then users will only select from third level terms.

[image]